# How to create new table within function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I created  one function, That function return the table values like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitText(@strArgs VARCHAR(4000))
    RETURNS @tab TABLE
    (
        [Key] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        Value VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES('Key1', 'Value1')
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES('Key2', 'Value2')

RETURN
END
GO

OUtput:
Key Value
*************
Key1    Value1
Key2    Value2
```

The second function i need,is to  return the table values from the above fuction.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TableValuedParameterExample11()
RETURNS  @TmpTable1  table (Value VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL) 
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @StateDescp VARCHAR(250)
 Select * into TmpTable1  from (Select value from dbo.Splittext('Test'))  aa

 RETURN  
END
GO
```

after finishing the functions,i  am running the below query.

`Select * from TmpTable1`.

Output i need

```
Value 
********
Value1
Value2
```

I need this out put.

But I got error

```
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SELECT INTO' within a function.
```

Comment: You need to use a stored procedure. DDL is not allowed in functions

Comment: its work but i need to call the function  many times. So need to over come i can use "Select * from TmpTable1" this query @Nadeem

Comment: If the TmpTable1 in the second function is a base table you cannot insert any record into it because functions can't you need to use a stored procedure, it will work with the declared table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `select * into [table]...` you must be sure the `[table]` doesnot exist. use `insert into [table] select ...` instead. also, you need a `@` when you deal with variable or function table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TableValuedParameterExample11()
RETURNS  @TmpTable1  table (Value VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL) 
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @StateDescp VARCHAR(250)
 INSERT INTO
    @TmpTable1([Value])
 SELECT 
    value 
 FROM 
    dbo.SplitArgs('Test'))  aa

 RETURN  
END
GO
```

Comment: After run this function. Can i use the Temptable.  Like this  "Select * from @TmpTable1". Tedo.G

Comment: No you cannot, but you can do a JOIN to this function like: `SELECT * FROM SomeTable s INNER JOIN dbo.TableValuedParameterExample1 () d ON d.[value]=s.[value]`

Comment: Pls explain with above sample @gofr1

Comment: @Meline I just have :) in my previous comment with query example. Also you can declare `@temptable` and insert from function into it like `INSERT INTO @temptable SELECT * FROM dbo.TableValuedParameterExample1 ()` or use `#temptable` like `SELECT * INTO #temptanle FROM dbo.Table aluedExample1 ()` and then work with `temtable`